# Start Java app on boot in Debian 7

Tags: java, debian

I have gone through almost every SO and Google article to try to make this happen but still the Java app isnt starting at boot!

I get a message in syslog to say its 'Starting FXC-API' but the Java doesnt actually run.

This is my startup script.

```
#! /bin/sh

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides: fxc-api
# Required-Start: $syslog exim4
# Required-Stop: $syslog
# Should-Start:
# Should-Stop:
# Default-Start: 2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop: 0 1 6
# Short-Description: Start and Stop
# Description:
### END INIT INFO


case "$1" in
  start)
    logger Starting FXC-API
    sh /opt/fix/fttglobal/1.0/start.sh
    ;;
  stop)
    logger Stopping FXC-API
    sh /opt/fix/fttglobal/1.0/stop.sh
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/fxc-api {start|stop}"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac

exit 0
```

If I run this manually, ie `service fxc-api start`, then it starts no problem.

The start.sh script looks like this

```
#! /bin/sh

cd "$(dirname "$0")"

java -classpath ".:./libs/*" MainController &
```

Answer (score 0):

Worked it out, I was missing the following in my `/etc/init.d` script above `case`

```
# Java path
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/java/jre
export JAVA_HOME
PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export PATH
```

A note: Run the java like this

```
java -classpath ".:./libs/*" MainController > ./logs/log.txt 2> ./logs/errors.txt < /dev/null &
```